# HTML input number value is cleared

Tags: html, validation, input

In Firefox or MS Edge, the value of an input number is cleared when the data is not valid : sometime the user type "1,5", sometime "1.5"

So how to by pass the validation by allowing both `,` (French) and `.` (English) ?

I tried `novalidate` and `formnovalidate` and none of them work when submitting data to the server (Apache)